# Short distance ball transport

Tags: kinematics, manipulator

I'm looking for a way to transport balls (diameter 50mm) 220 mm up with over a slope with a length of 120 mm. Currently I'm considering the usage of a belt system but I cannot seem to find a good belt system.

Because of space constraints within my robot, normally I would probably take a nylon belt and jam nails trough it to make little slots and then use that. However this would result in considerable reduction in available space as it means that I have to also take into account the extra space required for the nails on the way back. This means that ideally there would be a way to reduce the space used by the nails on the way back.

Does anybody have a good solution for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wanna stick to the belt system, then cut circular holes into the belt with a diameter of ~30mm. The ball will not fall through and can be transported upwards.

if you don't need much control over the ball, then you can "shoot" it with air pressure or a mechanical construction; something like a racket .

If you have enough place at the beginning of the slope, you could use a pneumatic actuator to push the ball.

Comment: That will work however the hole should have a size of at least 2*sin([angle of transport]). Which in this case comes up as closer to 40mm

Comment: Well but i suggest using a bigger hole then needed....this will improve reliability of the system.

Comment: Yes but not much as above 50mm there will be other problems.

Comment: For sure, if it's bigger then 50mm the ball will fall through.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to modify or mutilate a belt in any way to be able to use it as a ball elevator.

Simply place the belt upside-down *above* the balls, and and use it to roll the balls uphill.

[image: ball bearing animation] <-- similar to what's happening in this part of the animation

In this case, the inner ring represents your belt and the outer ring represents the ramp.